# Mule - CSV Lookup Table

Tags: mule

I have a mule flow with DataMapper configuration to map XML to JSON, in that I have a requirement to Lookup a CSV file which contains, for example, two columns and four rows to map to one of the JSON output field.

Below are my sample CSV file contents:

`Name,Contact
Ram,111-222
Kumar,222-333
John,333-444`

I got below exception while running DataMapper:

`Element [CSV:CSV]-Pre-Execution of lookup table [CSV:CSV]failed
Error when parsing record #2 field Name
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing error: Unexpected record delimiter, probably record has too few fields.`

When the CSV file contains only one row there is no exception.

Could any one provide me a way to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Please find the DataMapper configuration

```
<mule>
<data-mapper:config name="XML_To_JSON_1" transformationGraphPath="xml_to_json_1.grf" doc:name="XML_To_JSON" />
    <flow name="mule-csv-lookupFlow1" doc:name="mule-csv-lookupFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="XML_To_JSON_1" doc:name="XML To JSON" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Below is the `.grf` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Graph __version="3.5.0" author="pradeep" created="Wed Dec 03 13:06:48 IST 2014" description="XML To JSON" guiVersion="3.4.4.P" id="1417593604462" licenseCode="Unlicensed" licenseType="Unknown" modified="Wed Dec 03 13:06:48 IST 2014" modifiedBy="pradeep" name="XML_To_JSON" preview-file="${Project_Home}/src/main/resources/employee.xml" revision="1.0" showComponentDetails="false">
<Global>
<Metadata __index="0" __referenceCounter="1" __sourcePath="{}/object/contact" _dataStructure="SINGLE_DIMENSIONAL_COLLECTION" _id="__id" _metadataParentId="4430d2fe-5b06-4e39-b259-492c325fe164" _parent_id="__parent_id" _type="Output" id="f11ab87d-ec49-4034-a277-1e96a57b7925">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="contact" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field __artificialType="_parent_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__parent_id" type="string"/>
<Field __artificialType="_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__id" type="string"/>
<Field __index="0" __sourcePath="{}/object/contact/name" containerType="SINGLE" label="name" name="name" type="string"/>
<Field __index="1" __sourcePath="{}/object/contact/phone" containerType="SINGLE" label="phone" name="phone" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<Metadata _type="Lookup" id="963db4af-a7a1-428c-be6b-39af261e93d4">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="CSV" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field containerType="SINGLE" label="firstname" name="firstname" size="10" type="string"/>
<Field containerType="SINGLE" eofAsDelimiter="true" label="phone" name="phone" size="10" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<Metadata __index="0" __referenceCounter="1" __schemaType="employeeType" __sourcePath="{}/employees/employee" _dataStructure="SINGLE_DIMENSIONAL_COLLECTION" _id="__id" _metadataParentId="80f1c157-e81d-439d-afa8-e475de2dfe36" _parent_id="__parent_id" _type="Input" id="019cda9c-1078-4d00-bdcc-f81a59df5292">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="employee" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field __artificialType="_parent_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__parent_id" type="string"/>
<Field __artificialType="_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__id" type="string"/>
<Field __index="0" __schemaType="employeeType" __sourcePath="{}/employees/employee/@firstname" containerType="SINGLE" label="firstname" name="firstname" type="string"/>
<Field __index="1" __schemaType="employeeType" __sourcePath="{}/employees/employee/@lastname" containerType="SINGLE" label="lastname" name="lastname" type="string"/>
<Field __index="2" __schemaType="employeeType" __sourcePath="{}/employees/employee/@gender" containerType="SINGLE" label="gender" name="gender" type="string"/>
<Field __index="3" __schemaType="employeeType" __sourcePath="{}/employees/employee/@phone" containerType="SINGLE" label="phone" name="phone" type="string"/>
<Field __index="4" __schemaType="employeeType" __sourcePath="{}/employees/employee/@text()" containerType="SINGLE" label="text()" name="text" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<Metadata __filteredMetadata="false" __index="0" __referenceCounter="1" __schemaType="employeesType" __sourcePath="{}/employees" _dataStructure="OBJECT" _id="__id" _type="Input" id="80f1c157-e81d-439d-afa8-e475de2dfe36">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="employees" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field __artificialType="_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__id" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<Metadata __index="0" __referenceCounter="1" __sourcePath="{}/object" _dataStructure="OBJECT" _id="__id" _type="Output" id="4430d2fe-5b06-4e39-b259-492c325fe164">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="object" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field __artificialType="_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__id" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<LookupTable fileURL="D:/1_Ram/DEV/Workspace/mule-workspace/mule-datamapper-lookup/src/main/resources/staff.txt" id="CSV" key="phone" metadata="963db4af-a7a1-428c-be6b-39af261e93d4" name="CSV" type="simpleLookup">
<attr name="lookupType"><![CDATA[CSV]]></attr>
</LookupTable>
<Dictionary>
<Entry id="DictionaryEntry0" input="true" name="inputPayload" output="false" type="object"/>
<Entry id="DictionaryEntry1" input="false" name="outputPayload" output="true" type="object"/>
</Dictionary>
</Global>
<Phase number="0">
<Node enabled="enabled" guiName="Foreach 'employees' -&gt; 'object'" guiX="460" guiY="20" id="FOREACH_EMPLOYEES_OBJECT" transformClass="com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform" type="REFORMAT">
<attr name="melScript"><![CDATA[//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
]]></attr>
</Node>
<Node enabled="enabled" guiName="Foreach 'employee' -&gt; 'contact'" guiX="460" guiY="120" id="FOREACH_EMPLOYEE_CONTACT" transformClass="com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform" type="REFORMAT">
<attr name="melScript"><![CDATA[//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
output.__parent_id = input.__parent_id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.phone = input.phone + (isnull(lookup("CSV").get([input.firstname])) ? null : lookup("CSV").get([input.firstname]).phone);
output.name = input.lastname + ' ' + input.firstname;]]></attr>
</Node>
<Node cacheInMemory="true" charset="UTF-8" enabled="enabled" fileURL="dict:outputPayload" guiName="JSON WRITER" guiX="900" guiY="20" id="JSON_WRITER0" type="JSON_WRITER">
<attr name="mapping"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object xmlns:clover="http://www.cloveretl.com/ns/xmlmapping" clover:inPort="0">
  <clover:collection clover:name="contact">
    <item clover:inPort="1" clover:key="__parent_id" clover:parentKey="__id">
      <name>$1.name</name>
      <phone>$1.phone</phone>
    </item>
  </clover:collection>
</object>]]></attr>
<attr name="__isJsonSchema"><![CDATA[false]]></attr>
<attr name="_data_format"><![CDATA[JSON]]></attr>
<attr name="jsonSchemaURL"><![CDATA[./src/main/resources/contacts.json]]></attr>
</Node>
<Node charset="UTF-8" dataPolicy="strict" enabled="enabled" fileURL="dict:inputPayload" guiName="XML READER" guiX="20" guiY="20" id="XML_READER0" type="XML_READER">
<attr name="xmlSchemaURL"><![CDATA[./src/main/resources/employees.xsd]]></attr>
<attr name="mapping"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Context outPort="0" sequenceField="__id" xpath="/employees">
  <Context generatedKey="__parent_id" outPort="1" parentKey="__id" sequenceField="__id" xpath="employee">
    <Mapping cloverField="firstname" trim="true" xpath="@firstname"/>
    <Mapping cloverField="lastname" trim="true" xpath="@lastname"/>
    <Mapping cloverField="gender" trim="true" xpath="@gender"/>
    <Mapping cloverField="phone" trim="true" xpath="@phone"/>
    <Mapping cloverField="text" trim="true" xpath="text()"/>
  </Context>
</Context>
]]></attr>
<attr name="_data_format"><![CDATA[XML]]></attr>
<attr name="__rootGlobalElementName"><![CDATA[employees]]></attr>
</Node>
<Edge debugMode="true" fromNode="FOREACH_EMPLOYEES_OBJECT:0" guiBendpoints="" id="Edge1" inPort="Port 0 (in)" metadata="4430d2fe-5b06-4e39-b259-492c325fe164" outPort="Port 0 (out)" toNode="JSON_WRITER0:0"/>
<Edge debugMode="true" fromNode="FOREACH_EMPLOYEE_CONTACT:0" guiBendpoints="" id="Edge3" inPort="Port 1 (in)" metadata="f11ab87d-ec49-4034-a277-1e96a57b7925" outPort="Port 0 (out)" toNode="JSON_WRITER0:1"/>
<Edge debugMode="true" fromNode="XML_READER0:0" guiBendpoints="" id="Edge0" inPort="Port 0 (in)" metadata="80f1c157-e81d-439d-afa8-e475de2dfe36" outPort="Port 0 (out)" toNode="FOREACH_EMPLOYEES_OBJECT:0"/>
<Edge debugMode="true" fromNode="XML_READER0:1" guiBendpoints="" id="Edge2" inPort="Port 0 (in)" metadata="019cda9c-1078-4d00-bdcc-f81a59df5292" outPort="Port 1 (out)" toNode="FOREACH_EMPLOYEE_CONTACT:0"/>
</Phase>
</Graph>
```

Comment: could you share your datamapper configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the following issues in your .grf file:
1. CSV Record fields are firstname and phone while in your actual csv file they are Name and Contact (I assume the CSV sample in your original post matches what in staff.txt file).
2. LookupTable key is phone while you lookup based on name in your phone mapping

```
lookup("CSV").get([input.firstname]).phone
```